# Battle Engine for Text based browser game

Tags: c#, web, text-based, sql

I am starting to code a browser game, I have a rudimentary chat set up, and would like to start creating the battle engine, I have a general idea of how I want it to play out, but I don't know where I should do the calculations,

- SQL Server
- ASP.NET

I don't post JavaScript as an option because I don't want the user to be able to alter/hack the game that way.

What are the benefits and drawbacks of either method of coding the Battle Engine?

Comment: What tech to use is a rather personal question. What other requirements do you have? Also, ASP.NET doesn't run in a browser like JavaScript does—they're pretty much totally orthogonal unless you consider [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/). Really confused by that.

Comment: asp.net runs server side code, which is not Client side, and cannot be altered by client side, but a form submission can be run through code behind. I am not really sure why you would be Confused @Anko

Comment: The battle mechanics would take place in the code behind and then the results recorded in SQL Tables accordingly along with the Results returned in the response to the browser.